# Entering new/editing existing DB records with info from multiple tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So, I have a database for a mock phone site that has been built to the spec. My database has a table called phones, a table called operatingsystem and a table called manufacturer. I need to create a form to enter a new phone into the database. The problems I have run into are:

I need to basically get the form to add a new record to the **phones** table. However, the **phones** table pulls data from other tables as well. An example of this is how I have the operating systems (iOS, Android, BlackBerry and Windows Phone) stored separately in the **operatingsystem** table and each have an ID assigned (1, 2, 3 and 4) as well as having the manufacturers being stored in a **manufacturer** table (HTC, Samsung, Apple etc.) each with an auto increment ID. I'm not sure how I'd design the form so that the user can either add a new phone to the database simply by using the form or can add a new manufacturer/OS to the database if needed. I've got to do it assuming that the user adding the phones/editing existing ones hasn't got access to the database so obviously they don't know that manufacturer ID 1 is Apple, 2 Samsung etc.

I basically need to use a combination of a HTML form and accompanying PHP page so that phones can be added, edited or deleted altogether from the database. What would I do in terms of form design and what PHP would I need to use to be able to add/edit/delete data from multiple tables?

Sorry for the long-winded post but any help would be appreciated and if any more details are needed, please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the manufacturer and operating system, the `<select>` element is the obvious choice. It creates a drop-down with selectable options, with a potential separation between the value passed and what the user sees.

So, if you had this:

```
<select name="manufacturer">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">HTC</option>
    <option value="3">Samsung</option>
</select>
```

then the user would see Apple, HTC and Samsung as options. If they selected Samsung, then what would actually be submitted as that parameter's value is `3` (which would correspond to the id in your table).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple/quick solution, @Anthony Grist's answer would do it. But, if you are aiming to build an automatized system that can 'live' on it's own, you'd need to build a `<select>` from PHP with the options that already exists and allow the user to add stuffs inside this `<select>` through a different CRUD. The problem with this is that users would be allowed to insert iOS, iOS 5, iOS 6, iOSasdf, etc; as they wish because you wouldn't be able to block it this much. If this is the case that you'd like to go, I'd suggest you to create a table to which you would use to feed the `<select>` in which table you'd have the `operation_system` and the `table_name`. If a new OS is being added, you'd use PHP to create a new table for this OS and then add it's name to the said table. When users select a OS in the select option, you'd pick that table and insert the record to it.

Comment: The implication in my answer was that they'd build the select dynamically, I just didn't think it was necessary to explicitly spell that out. Not to mention that I don't know PHP so providing even vaguely useful code in that respect wouldn't have been an option. I'd also say that one table per operating system is awful database design; your table for storing phones should link in to the OS and manufacturer tables using the correct `id`.